# Dropping a data-frame column based on last row values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data-frame which looks like the following. How do I selectively drop the columns where the final value in each row (10-jul-18) is <0.3?

i.e return a dataframe with column A and column D dropped?

From this:

[image]

to give:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

given that your DataFrame is called df, you can do this the following way:

```
columns_to_keep = df.iloc[-1, :]>=0.3
new_df = df.loc[:, columns_to_keep]
```

in this case `df.iloc[-1, :]` takes the last row as a `pd.Series`. `>=0.3` will create a boolean Series which we can then use with `.loc` to only keep the columns for which the last row's value is bigger than or equal to 0.3.

I have prepared a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) below:

```
In [7]: import pandas as pd
In [8]: df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[0.1, 0.1, 0.2], 'B':[0.2, 0.3, 0.3], 'C':[0.2, 0.4, 0.4], 'D':[0.2, 0.2, 0.2], 'E':[0.1, 0.2, 0.4], 'F':[0.3
   ...: , 0.3, 0.4]}, index=['08-Jul-18', '09-Jul-18', '10-Jul-18'])

In [9]: df
Out[9]: 
             A    B    C    D    E    F
08-Jul-18  0.1  0.2  0.2  0.2  0.1  0.3
09-Jul-18  0.1  0.3  0.4  0.2  0.2  0.3
10-Jul-18  0.2  0.3  0.4  0.2  0.4  0.4

In [10]: df.loc[:, df.iloc[-1, :] >=.3]
Out[10]: 
             B    C    E    F
08-Jul-18  0.2  0.2  0.1  0.3
09-Jul-18  0.3  0.4  0.2  0.3
10-Jul-18  0.3  0.4  0.4  0.4
```

Comment: If this answers your question, please accept it also.

Comment: Thanks. This provides me with an Index... how do I create the dataframe which then contains only columns BCE&F?

Comment: No, this should give you exactly that DataFrame, please take a look at the edits I made to the answer.

Comment: I get Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: [2017-07-14 00:00:00, 2017-07-17 00:00:00....]

Comment: Then the way you are constructing your DataFrame is off. See the minimal example I just added.

Comment: Just pinging this again, do you understand the minimal example I added? Does that help with your issue?